# openssl port v1.0 to v3.0 - Pseudo Random Function output is different

Tags: c++, openssl

I'm porting a Pseudo Random Function (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-5)  from openssl 1.0 to 3.0 and have done something wrong, because I'm getting different output in the second iteration. The example code has the original v1.0 PRF, and my attempt at v3.0; these get called with the same data and should produce the same output:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <ios>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "openssl/core_names.h"
#include "openssl/hmac.h"

// Pseudo Random Function, see: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-5

// use older v1.1 API
bool PRF_Hash_11(const EVP_MD* hashmethod, const std::vector<uint8_t>& secret, const std::vector<uint8_t>& seed, size_t outputlen, std::vector<uint8_t>& output)
{
    if (hashmethod == 0)
        return false;

    output.clear();

    if (outputlen == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    //calculate how big the output needs to be
    int size = EVP_MD_size(hashmethod);
    size_t iterations = (outputlen / size);

    if ((outputlen % size) != 0)
        ++iterations;

    output.resize(size * iterations);

    std::vector<uint8_t> An(EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE);
    unsigned int accumulatorLen = 0;
    unsigned int offset = 0;
    unsigned int outputsize = 0;

    HMAC_CTX* ctx = HMAC_CTX_new();
    HMAC_Init_ex(ctx, secret.data(), static_cast<int>(secret.size()), hashmethod, 0);

    //this context generates A(n)
    HMAC_CTX* ctx_hash = HMAC_CTX_new();
    HMAC_Init_ex(ctx_hash, secret.data(), static_cast<int>(secret.size()), hashmethod, 0);

    //calculate A(1)
    HMAC_Update(ctx_hash, seed.data(), seed.size());
    HMAC_Final(ctx_hash, An.data(), &accumulatorLen);

    for (size_t i = 1; i <= iterations; ++i)
    {
        //reinitialize the hash for the next iteration
        HMAC_Init_ex(ctx, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        HMAC_Update(ctx, An.data(), accumulatorLen);
        HMAC_Update(ctx, seed.data(), seed.size());
        HMAC_Final(ctx, output.data() + offset, &outputsize);

        offset += outputsize;

        if (i < iterations) {
            //calculate the next A(i)
            HMAC_Init_ex(ctx_hash, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            HMAC_Update(ctx_hash, An.data(), accumulatorLen);
            HMAC_Final(ctx_hash, An.data(), &accumulatorLen);
        }
    }

    output.resize(outputlen);

    HMAC_CTX_free(ctx);
    HMAC_CTX_free(ctx_hash);

    return true;
}

// use 3.0 API
bool PRF_Hash_30(const char* digname, int hash_size, const std::vector<uint8_t>& secret, const std::vector<uint8_t>& seed, size_t outputlen, std::vector<uint8_t>& output)
{
    output.clear();
    if (outputlen == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    //calculate how big the output needs to be
    size_t iterations = (outputlen / hash_size);

    if ((outputlen % hash_size) != 0)
        ++iterations;

    output.resize(hash_size * iterations);

    auto* ossl_ctxt = OSSL_LIB_CTX_new();
    EVP_MAC* hmac = EVP_MAC_fetch(ossl_ctxt, "HMAC", NULL);
    if (hmac == NULL) { return false; }

    OSSL_PARAM params[2];
    params[0] = OSSL_PARAM_construct_utf8_string(OSSL_MAC_PARAM_DIGEST, (char*)digname, 0);
    params[1] = OSSL_PARAM_construct_end();

    std::vector<uint8_t> An(EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE);
    size_t accumulatorLen = 0;
    size_t offset = 0;
    size_t outputsize = 0;

    // working context
    auto* wctx = EVP_MAC_CTX_new(hmac);
    if (wctx == NULL) { return false; }
    int res = EVP_MAC_init(wctx, secret.data(), secret.size(), params);

    // this context generates A(n)
    auto* hctx = EVP_MAC_CTX_new(hmac);
    if (hctx == NULL) { return false; }
    res = EVP_MAC_init(hctx, secret.data(), secret.size(), params);

    //calculate A(1)
    res = EVP_MAC_update(hctx, seed.data(), seed.size());
    res = EVP_MAC_final(hctx, An.data(), &accumulatorLen, EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE);

    for (size_t i = 1; i <= iterations; ++i)
    {
        res = EVP_MAC_init(wctx, 0, 0, params); //reinitialize the hash for the next iteration
        res = EVP_MAC_update(wctx, An.data(), accumulatorLen);
        res = EVP_MAC_update(wctx, seed.data(), seed.size());
        res = EVP_MAC_final(wctx, output.data() + offset, &outputsize, EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE);

        offset += outputsize;

        if (i < iterations) {
            //calculate the next A(i)
            res = EVP_MAC_init(hctx, 0, 0, params); //reinitialize the hash for the next iteration
            res = EVP_MAC_update(hctx, An.data(), accumulatorLen);
            res = EVP_MAC_final(hctx, An.data(), &accumulatorLen, EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE);
        }
    }

    output.resize(outputlen);

    EVP_MAC_CTX_free(hctx);
    EVP_MAC_CTX_free(wctx);
    EVP_MAC_free(hmac);
    OSSL_LIB_CTX_free(ossl_ctxt);

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    const std::vector<uint8_t> secret {
        0x01, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88, 0x99, 0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff, 0x01, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88, 0x99, 0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff,
        0x01, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88, 0x99, 0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff};

    const std::vector<uint8_t> seed {
        0x6b, 0x65, 0x79, 0x20, 0x65, 0x78, 0x70, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x73, 0x69, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0xb1, 0x26, 0x07, 0x8d, 0xec, 0x68, 0x2e, 0x69, 0xe7, 0x6d, 0xc1, 0xaa, 0x88, 0xcb, 0xfe, 0xa5, 0x94, 0xd9, 0x82,
        0xa6, 0x0f, 0x2d, 0x32, 0xa0, 0xde, 0x7e, 0x55, 0x8d, 0xf8, 0x1b, 0x83, 0x80, 0xfa, 0x42, 0xa3, 0x0b, 0x6c, 0xad, 0xbf, 0x24, 0x78, 0xb2, 0xbb, 0xfa, 0xa3, 0x5a, 0x98, 0x84, 0xe4, 0x54, 0x10,
        0x2b, 0x46, 0xc0, 0x91, 0x34, 0x96, 0x2e, 0x64, 0x34, 0x73, 0xba, 0x3d, 0xa1};

    // use SHA-384 and 72 bytes out for this test
    const EVP_MD* hashmethod = EVP_sha384();    
    int hash_size = EVP_MD_size(hashmethod);
    const char * digname = OSSL_DIGEST_NAME_SHA2_384;
    constexpr size_t bufsize = 0x48;    // # output bytes needed

    std::vector<uint8_t> output_v1, output_v3;
    output_v1.reserve(bufsize);
    output_v3.reserve(bufsize);

    // generate output using old and new API
    bool ret = PRF_Hash_11(hashmethod, secret, seed, output_v1.capacity(), output_v1);
    ret = PRF_Hash_30(digname, hash_size, secret, seed, output_v3.capacity(), output_v3);

    // print output
    auto prnthex = [](std::vector<uint8_t> v) {
        std::stringstream stream;
        for (auto e : v) {
            stream << ' ' << std::hex << (e / 16) << (e & 0x0F);
        }
        std::cout << stream.str() << std::endl;
    };

    prnthex(output_v1);
    prnthex(output_v3);

    auto pr = std::mismatch(output_v1.begin(), output_v1.end(), output_v3.begin(), output_v3.end());
    std::cout << std::endl << " mismatch at output[" << std::distance(output_v1.begin(), pr.first) << ']' << std::endl;
}
```

output is:

```
21 50 34 fe f0 c6 de 4b e8 e6 df 65 21 36 11 a0 24 30 18 a5 42 74 d8 e5 5f 82 41 ed 4a ef 55 27 e0 b6 c4 fc 95 a8 10 be 35 b9 94 06 3a c9 59 56 4c 4c 2c 2a 01 d2 38 c3 a7 80 40 20 b3 5a 98 7f f3 9d 9c 72 96 b0 61 39
21 50 34 fe f0 c6 de 4b e8 e6 df 65 21 36 11 a0 24 30 18 a5 42 74 d8 e5 5f 82 41 ed 4a ef 55 27 e0 b6 c4 fc 95 a8 10 be 35 b9 94 06 3a c9 59 56 80 50 68 12 4e 46 25 e0 47 91 98 10 08 68 0c ba fa 35 73 9f b1 63 13 af

mismatch at output[48]
```

I'm a newb and am not seeing what is wrong here. Anyone else find the openssl docs a bit hard to interpret?

Answer (score 0):

behavior of v3 EVP_MAC_init() is different than v1 HMAC_Init_ex in regards to the key: passing null in v1 re-uses the key, this is not true in v3.
calls inside the loop

> res = EVP_MAC_init(hctx, 0, 0, params);

should be replaced with

> res = EVP_MAC_init(hctx, secret.data(), secret.size(), params);